# Setting Button in listview Visibility to False if query result is "0"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am building a web application in ASP.net and I have a little problem.

I have a LISTVIEW to display data from a data source, and in that listview I have included a BUTTON in every row to be visible if the result of the query in the Page_load is 0.

The Query works, but I don't know how to select the button in the query.

I have tried

```
ListView1.FindControl("hiddenButton").visible = false;
```

this is the buttons code

```
<asp:Button ID="hiddenButton" runat="server" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>' Text="Add Friend" CssClass="btn btn-info pull-right" OnClick="addFriend_Click" Width="105px" allign="right"/>
```

But its not working.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're adding the button to the rows?

Comment: Khlr, i have edited the question to add the buttons code.thanks

Comment: Did you get a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `ItemDataBound` event:-

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType==ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            if (YourCondition)
            {
                Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("hiddenButton");
                hdn.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to associate this event handler in your mark-up(if not already done):-

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
       </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ItemDataBound` event To set Buttons visible to `True/False`

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
       Button hiddenButton=(Button) dataItem.FindControl("hiddenButton");
       hiddenButton.Visible = false;           

    }

}
```